# Running tests for specific method in SAGE

Tags: sage

I know there is possible to run tests for specific lines and methods in some languages/frameworks as for example Ruby on Rails. I would like to know if there is some specific syntax to do the same in SAGE math. For example, suppose I have the next code. I would like to run only the EXAMPLES of method1 with something like `sage -t module.py:method1`

```
#module.py

def method1():
    """
    EXAMPLES::
     
    sage: 5+0
    5
    """
    return 1

def method2():
    """
    EXAMPLES::
     
    sage: 5+2
    7
    """
    return 2
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Do you want to run method1 only? Do you want to unit test method1? Do you want to run the code snippet (5+0) of method1 but you don't want to execute the rest of method1?